# How to fill pandas dataframes in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to build a subset of dataframes from a larger dataframe by searching for a string in the column headings.

```py
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
cdf = df.drop(['DateTime'], axis=1)

wells = ['N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9']
for well in wells:
    wellname = well
    well = pd.DataFrame()
    well_cols = [col for col in cdf.columns if wellname in col]
    well = cdf[well_cols]
```

I am trying to search for the wellname in the cdf dataframe columns and put those columns which contain that wellname into a new dataframe named the wellname.

I am able to build my new sub dataframes but the dataframes come up empty of size (0, 0) while cdf is (21973, 91).

well_cols also populates correctly as a list.

These are some of cdf column headings.  Each column has 20k rows of data.

```
Index(['N1_Inj_Casing_Gas_Valve', 'N1_LT_Stm_Rate', 'N1_ST_Stm_Rate',
       'N1_Inj_Casing_Gas_Flow_Rate', 'N1_LT_Stm_Valve', 'N1_ST_Stm_Valve',
       'N1_LT_Stm_Pressure', 'N1_ST_Stm_Pressure', 'N1_Bubble_Tube_Pressure',
       'N1_Inj_Casing_Gas_Pressure', 'N2_Inj_Casing_Gas_Valve',
       'N2_LT_Stm_Rate', 'N2_ST_Stm_Rate', 'N2_Inj_Casing_Gas_Flow_Rate',
       'N2_LT_Stm_Valve', 'N2_ST_Stm_Valve', 'N2_LT_Stm_Pressure',
       'N2_ST_Stm_Pressure', 'N2_Bubble_Tube_Pressure',
       'N2_Inj_Casing_Gas_Pressure', 'N3_Inj_Casing_Gas_Valve',
       'N3_LT_Stm_Rate', 'N3_ST_Stm_Rate', 'N3_Inj_Casing_Gas_Flow_Rate',
       'N3_LT_Stm_Valve', 'N3_ST_Stm_Valve', 'N3_LT_Stm_Pressure',
```

I want to create a new dataframe with every heading that contains the "well" IE a new dataframe for all columns & data with column name containing N1, another for N2 etc.

The New dataframes populate correctly when inside the loop but disappear when the loop breaks...  a bit of the code output for `print(well)`:

```
[27884 rows x 10 columns]
       N9_Inj_Casing_Gas_Valve  ...  N9_Inj_Casing_Gas_Pressure
0                    74.375000  ...                 2485.602364
1                    74.520833  ...                 2485.346000
2                    74.437500  ...                 2485.341091
```

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and a desired output so it easier for us to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of an array are not mutable when iterating over it. That is, here's what it's doing based on your example:

```
# 1st iteration
well = 'N1' # assigned by the for loop directive
...
well = <empty DataFrame> # assigned by `well = pd.DataFrame()`
...
well = <DataFrame, subset of cdf where col has 'N1' in name> # assigned by `well = cdf[well_cols]`
# 2nd iteration
well = 'N2' # assigned by the for loop directive
...
well = <empty DataFrame> # assigned by `well = pd.DataFrame()`
...
well = <DataFrame, subset of cdf where col has 'N2' in name> # assigned by `well = cdf[well_cols]`
...
```

But at no point did you change the array, or store the new dataframes for that matter (although you would still have the last dataframe stored in `well` at the end of the iteration).

IMO, it seems like storing the dataframes in a dict would be easier to use:

```py
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
cdf = df.drop(['DateTime'], axis=1)

wells = ['N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9']
well_dfs = {}
for well in wells:
    well_cols = [col for col in cdf.columns if well in col]
    well_dfs[well] = cdf[well_cols]
```

However, if you really want it in a list, you could do something like:

```py
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
cdf = df.drop(['DateTime'], axis=1)

wells = ['N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9']
for ix, well in enumerate(wells):
    well_cols = [col for col in cdf.columns if well in col]
    wells[ix] = cdf[well_cols]
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am fairly new to python and I see now that I have my new dictionary variable containing all of the data.  I next have to do a lot of data cleaning steps on the dataframes which i was hoping to do in the loop as well.  I am then trying to create an ensemble model based on the individual "wells" in the data.  I may have to learn some new skills to now work with these dictionary sub dataframes that I was previously used to doing with the general pandas library. There might be an easier way to create my ensemble models just using the main dataframe...

Comment: @MA No worries. You can write functions that do what you want on each DataFrame, then iterate over your dict values and pass them to the function. Without knowing more about your data and what you're trying to accomplish, I can't be more specific. However, if this helped solve your current question, feel free to accept and/or upvote it :)

Comment: Can I make those dictionary sub dataframes into actual dataframes outside of the loop?  for instance: `N1 = DataFrame.from_dict` or something (I'll need to research the syntax)

Comment: @MA the dict would simply contain a reference to each of the dataframes, they already live 'outside the loop'. You can then access the dataframes through the dict. For example, if you wanted the N1 dataframe, you would just do `well_dfs['N1']`. If you really wanted to have a variable named N1, you could assign the sub dataframes to: `globals()[well]` inside the for loop instead. That would create a variable named w/e is the value stored in `well` into the global scope. However, that is pretty hacky and not recommended for 'production' code.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! I was a little hesitant to start working with the dictionaries but they seem easy.  As a final question: how do I call a particular column from one of the dataframes in the dictionary?  for Ex if I wanted to add one column to another.. something like `well_dfs['N1': 'LT_Stm_Rate']`?

Comment: @MA you would do `well_dfs['N1']['LT_Stm_Rate']`. However, based on your example, you would have no column named `LT_Stm_Rate`; you would instead have `N1_LT_Stm_Rage` since you never removed the `N1_` from the col name. It might be better to remove that using something like `wells[ix].rename(lambda x: x.replace(well + '_', ''), axis=1, inplace=True)` in the for loop, this would make it easier to write functions to act on each dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC this should be enough:

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
cdf = df.drop(['DateTime'], axis=1)

wells = ['N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9']
well_dict={}
for well in wells:

    well_cols = [col for col in cdf.columns if well in col]
    well_dict[well] = cdf[well_cols]
```

Dictionaries are usually the way to go if you want to populate something. In this case, then, if you input `well_dict['N1']`, you'll get your first dataframe, and so on.

Comment: my dataframes still come up blank on this.

Comment: Could you post the first 10 or so elements of `cdf.columns` ?

Comment: In original post.

Comment: if you add `print(cdf.shape)` after `well = cdf[well_cols]` is it always 0 ?

Comment: No, it is the size of the original dataframe.  In fact my dataframes actually populate correctly if i print while I'm still inside the loop they just disappear after the loop ends.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, items in a list are not mutable in a for loop. That is, inside your for loop, it's going to assign the current element to a variable named `well`. If you assign anything to `well` inside the for loop code block, it's only changing it for that (local) variable, not for the element in the list. This means that as soon as you enter the next iteration that value is lost, since `well` will now hold the next value in the list. See the second part of my answer for how to actually change the value in the array.

Comment: Altered my answer with a better understanding of your problem. Saving in a dictionary is usually better than a list, as they are more flexible

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach the problem is to use `pd.MultiIndex` and `Groupby`.

You can add the construct a MultiIndex composed of well identifier and variable name. If you have `df`:

```
   N1_a  N1_b  N2_a  N2_b
1     2     2     3     4
2     7     8     9    10
```

You can use `df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)` to parse the well identifer corresponding variable name (i.e. `a` or `b`).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns=df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)).sort_index(1)
```

Which returns:

```
  N1    N2    
   a  b  a   b
0  2  2  3   4
1  7  8  9  10
```

Then you can transpose the data frame and `groupby` the MultiIndex level 0.

```
grouped = df.T.groupby(level=0)
```

To return a list of  untransposed sub-data frames you can use:

```
wells = [group.T for _, group in grouped]
```

where `wells[0]` is:

```
  N1   
   a  b
0  2  2
1  7  8
```

and `wells[1]` is:

```
  N2    
   a   b
0  3   4
1  9  10
```

The last step is rather unnecessary because the data can be accessed from the grouped object `grouped`.

All together:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
N1_a,N1_b,N2_a,N2_b
1,2,2,3,4
2,7,8,9,10
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data)) 

# Parse Column names to add well name to multiindex level
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns=df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)).sort_index(1)

# Group by well name
grouped = df.T.groupby(level=0)

#bulist list of sub dataframes
wells = [group.T for _, group in grouped]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `contains`

```
df[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(wells))]
```